# Complex inputs to neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, data-transformation

I'm quite new to machine learning and is trying to predict waiting times in a telephone-queue using a feedforward neural network. I have a lot of historical data for supervised training and i'm trying to map the data to an input-layer.

Each person in the queue have some properties and are being prioritized by the secretaries based on these properties(meaning that the queue isn't FIFO).

```
personInQueue {
    memberShip: 1, //platinum-membership
    seniority: 2, // an important customer
    minutesWaited: 12
}
```

My initial thought of mapping the data to an input layer was to simply make every property available as an input. That would look something like the following:

```
Inputs:
PersonImCurrentlyTryingToEstimate-Membership
PersonImCurrentlyTryingToEstimate-Seniority
PersonImCurrentlyTryingToEstimate-MinutesWaited
OtherPersonInTheQueue1-Membership
OtherPersonInTheQueue1-Seniority
OtherPersonInTheQueue1-MinutesWaited
OtherPersonInTheQueue2-Membership
OtherPersonInTheQueue2-Seniority
OtherPersonInTheQueue2-MinutesWaited
...
```

But the network can't have a flexible amount of inputs. Is this at all the right direction to go, or could it be that a neural network simply isn't the right approach, or should I do some sort of data-transformation?

EDIT:

Another approach could(as suggested by Hugh) be to use summery statistics:

```
Inputs:
PersonImCurrentlyTryingToEstimate-Membership
PersonImCurrentlyTryingToEstimate-Seniority
PersonImCurrentlyTryingToEstimate-MinutesWaited
AmountOfPeopleWithSeniority1
MeanOfWaitingTimeForPeopleWithSeniority1
SDOfWaitingTimeForPeopleWithSeniority1
AmountOfPeopleWithSeniority2
MeanOfWaitingTimeForPeopleWithSeniority2
SDOfWaitingTimeForPeopleWithSeniority2
AmountOfPeopleWithSeniority3
MeanOfWaitingTimeForPeopleWithSeniority3
SDOfWaitingTimeForPeopleWithSeniority3
```

Comment: This type of sequential data is better modeled by a recurrent neural network.

Comment: But is it necessarily a sequence? People in the queue might come an go depending on the these parameters. It isn't a FIFO queue.

Comment: Ok I was assuming it was a FIFO queue. One approach is to use a fixed number of summary statistics. As an example, ignoring the membership, you could input the number of people with seniority=1, the mean of their waiting times and the standard deviation of their waiting times, then the same for seniority=2

Comment: That sounds like a pretty good idea. Just edited my question. Something along those lines? Trying to reason about if it would provide a predictable output ;-)

Comment: Yes that's exactly the input layer I meant in my example. I don't know how exactly you can include the membership types. I think you'll need to decide this yourself based on whether membership or seniority is more important, and also whether you have data suitable for training with both membership and seniority information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's all beginning to make sense in my head! One quick follow-up question, why is the StdDev important in this case? (it's probably obvious, but my brain is overcomplicating things right now)

Comment: Glad I could help. If the waiting time of the new person is linearly related to the waiting times of every other person in the queue then just using the average waiting time gives all the information that's needed. But if the relationship is quadratic then the distribution of the values around the mean becomes important.